# Navigating to directory with spaces not possible anymore

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I'm realtivly new to bash as having always developed on a windows machine (yeah i know). Until recently I have been able to cd into a dir by using

```
cd a\ dir\ name\ with\ spaces/
```

but suddenly this does not work any longer. Even using TAB auto-complete it will generate the proper escapes but I'm always met with something like

```
-bash: cd: a: No such file or directory
```

a friend mentioned it may be path related. Can anyone shed some light on this issue for me?

---

Below is my `.bash_profile`

```
# Exe subshell script
source ~/.bashrc
```

And the `.bashrc`

```
function cs ()
{
  cd $1
  ls
}

# A new version of "cd" which
# prints the directory after cd'ing
cd() {
        builtin cd $1
        pwd
}
```

Comment: *it will generate the correct command* meaning it will generate the escapes properly? I can't imagine it "suddenly" doesn't work. Have you altered any of bash's personal configuration files (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`)?

Comment: have edited. Yes I did edit bash_profile. I just had a look and commented out my last edit 'source ~/.bashrc' and it works again! This was to add an extra function 'cs' that is contained in .bash_rc using a similar approach described http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html for osX. Any idea why this stops escaping spaces working?

Comment: done, have added to OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A correct replacement would be:

```
cd() {
    builtin cd "$1"
    pwd
}
```

You need to quote a variable that contains spaces when it's expanded if you want to retain them.

---

#### Why do I need to do this?

Let's examine:

- Let's say you call your custom `cd` function with the argument `with\ spaces`.
- Obviously, you need to do this, since otherwise, your function would get *two* arguments, namely `with` and `spaces`.
- So, correctly escaping, your function gets `with spaces` as *one* argument.
- You pass this argument to `builtin cd` using `$1`.
- `$1` is automatically expanded to `with spaces` (since that's what the function received).
- Your call now is `builtin cd with spaces/`
- That again results in a call to `cd` with the *two* arguments `with` and `spaces`.

So to fix it:

- Quote `$1` with [double quotes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html).
- The command is expanded to `builtin cd "with spaces"`.
- Now `cd` is correctly called with *one* argument again.

---

Another possibility is to just use a more generic `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` to pass *all* parameters and not only the first one to another script. This is what you want to do in 99% of all cases.

```
cd() {
    builtin cd "$@"
    pwd
}
```

Obviously, the same fix applies to your `cs()` function.

Comment: +1 Also need to quote the "$1" in the `cs` function.